# Heteroscedastic LR improves parameter estimates

Tags: generalized-linear-model, linear-model, heteroscedasticity

Let's say I have 1d data generated using linear function, and heteroscedastic noise on top of it, whose distribution I happen to know. I can estimate parameters using least squares linear regression with uniform weights, or with weights derived from the distribution of the noise. I guess in the latter case I should be able to see that my estimates of the intercept and the slope are somewhat better. How could I express this in quantitative terms? E.g. perhaps I should expect that confidence intervals become tighter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should see increase in likelihood for both training and test sample if the likelihood is calculated using the true noise values.

Regarding confidence intervals - they would be roughly the same size. What we are encountering here is model misspecification: you obtain confidence intervals each time under different assumptions (with and without heteroscedasticity). So, it isn't correct to compare them.

May be, if you use bootstrap-like procedure to estimate confidence intervals - you'll get tighter bounds in a heteorscedastic case, as for bootstrap you make no assumptions about the true distribution and derive this true distribution from the data.

Comment: Indeed, I was worried that if I use confidence interval method, it would give different estimates depending on the assumptions on the model of the noise. *if the likelihood is calculated using the true noise values* isn't these true noise values also relate to different assumptions on the noise distribution?

Comment: @Ilya Yes, the assumption about noise (i.e. homo- or heterscedasticity or distribution of noise) specify the true model, so in each case you get as a result a model that fits your assumptions best.

Comment: Thanks. Could you hint on how could I compute the likelihood of estimates in both cases (weighted, non-weighted)? I never did this before, perhaps where to read on it?

Comment: @Ilya For standrad normal noise for linear model such that we have a sample of $(x_i, y_i, \sigma^2_i)_{i = 1}^n$, where $x_i$ are input variables, $y_i$ are output variables, $\sigma^2_i$ are noise variances, and model is $\hat{y}(x)$ the likelihood is up to the constant: $\frac12 (\prod_{i = 1}^n \log \sigma^2_i + \sum_{i = 1}^n \frac{(y_i - \hat{y}(x_i))^2}{\sigma_i^2})$

Comment: Just a question on formula, is that really a product of logs in the first term? Also, I guess that likelihood should be negative of that formula, since in case there's a perfect match, likelihood should go up (the value of the current formula goes down).

Comment: @Ilya You are right: 1. There should be minus before the formula. 2. It is not likelihood, but logarithm of likelihood.

Comment: Thanks, so sum instead of a product in the first term?

Comment: @Ilya Yes, of course